# Change color of class inside visited link

Tags: html, css

I have a class inside a link tag like this:

```
<a class="title" href="page.php" >some text and <span class="highlight" > keyword</span></a>
```

css:

```
a:visited{
color: purple;
}
.highlight{
color: yellow;
}
```

when i click the link it becomes purple but the keyword remains yellow, what to do?

Comment: like this demo??? - http://jsfiddle.net/yzv8tLf0/

Comment: @MaryMelody yep, can you make this an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yzv8tLf0/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<a class="title" href="#">some text and <span class="highlight" > keyword</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:visited, a:visited > .highlight {
    color: purple;
}
.highlight {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to style elements matching `.highlight` when they are inside a visited link differently to ones outside a visited link, then you need to write two rule-sets for it.

Use a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

```
.highlight {
  /* regular */
}

a:visited .highlight {
  /* inside a visited link */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css:

```
 a:hover, a:hover > span{color: purple;}
```